# How to filter list of dictionaries based on a string value and two dates

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
[{'ID': 17, 'DATE': '20161123', 'VAL': 100},
               {'ID': 26, 'DATE': '20161223', 'VAL': 500   },
               {'ID': 26, 'DATE': '20161023','VAL': 300   },
               {'ID': 26, 'DATE': '20161013','VAL': 400   },
               {'ID': 17, 'DATE': '20161103', 'VAL': 150   },
               {'ID': 17, 'DATE': '20161023', 'VAL': 250  }]
dates= [20161001, 20161025]
ID = 26
```

How can filter based on ID and date between two specific dates to get specific rows?

```
result = [{'ID': 26, 'DATE': '20161023','VAL': 300   },
                   {'ID': 26, 'DATE': '20161013','VAL': 400   }]
```

Comment: Have a look at [strptime('%Y%m%d', ...)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and fiddle around and see what works.

Comment: You need to convert DATE to date with datetime.datetime. Then define filter function which returns True/False and then filter list by filter fucntion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As your date is in `YYYYMMDD` format, normal string ordering will do. Try like this (Python 2.7.14):

```
>>> d = [{'ID': 17, 'DATE': '20161123', 'VAL': 100},
               {'ID': 26, 'DATE': '20161223', 'VAL': 500   },
               {'ID': 26, 'DATE': '20161023','VAL': 300   },
               {'ID': 26, 'DATE': '20161013','VAL': 400   },
               {'ID': 17, 'DATE': '20161103', 'VAL': 150   },
               {'ID': 17, 'DATE': '20161023', 'VAL': 250  }]
>>> 
>>> dates= [20161001, 20161025]
>>> ID = 26
>>> dates = map(str,dates) # for Python 3.x you need to make it a list by: list(map(str,dates)). Or you can use list comprehension: [str(x) for x in dates]
>>> result = [e for e in d if e['ID']==ID and dates[0]<= e['DATE']<=dates[1]]
>>> result
[{'DATE': '20161023', 'ID': 26, 'VAL': 300}, {'DATE': '20161013', 'ID': 26, 'VAL': 400}]
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: The above code was copy-pasted _after_ running it in the IDLE. So I guess there is problem in your `dates` variable. Or may be you are running `python 3`?

Comment: I copy and pasted your code, I can screenshot if you'd like :) Odds are you're running Python 2. Also, `date[x]` is of type str, and the dates list has integers. None of which uses actual date objects.

Comment: Yeah. When any question does not have Python version mentioned, I take it for Python 2.7 by default.

Comment: I recommend you don't. It's worth trying to get people to move over from Python2 to Python3. And also assume your code should work on both platforms. A simple example of this would be `dates = list(map(str, dates))`. That essentially makes the code work in Python2 AND in Python3. But again, assume Pyton3, and try to write your code for both would probably be a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

Using `list comprehension` and [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert to `datetime` format:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

#convert to datetime format
>>> date1 = datetime.strptime(str(dates[0]),'%Y%m%d')
>>> date2 = datetime.strptime(str(dates[1]),'%Y%m%d')

>>> out = [ ele for ele in l if ele['ID']==ID and
                date1 <= datetime.strptime(ele['DATE'],'%Y%m%d') <= date2 ]

>>> out
=> [{'ID': 26, 'DATE': '20161023', 'VAL': 300}, {'ID': 26, 'DATE': '20161013', 'VAL': 400}]
```

#driver values :

```
IN : l=[{'ID': 17, 'DATE': '20161123', 'VAL': 100},
           {'ID': 26, 'DATE': '20161223', 'VAL': 500},
           {'ID': 26, 'DATE': '20161023','VAL': 300},
           {'ID': 26, 'DATE': '20161013','VAL': 400},
           {'ID': 17, 'DATE': '20161103', 'VAL': 150},
           {'ID': 17, 'DATE': '20161023', 'VAL': 250}]

IN : dates= [20161001, 20161025]
ID = 26
```

Comment: why do we need to convert to datetime. Can't we just convert the dates to string type since in the dictionary the date is a string ?

Comment: @VinnyKaur : superficially, that would seem to be the case. But its a better bet to always convert to the `appropriate datatype` before doing any computations on them.Though it might work now because of sheer luck and the requirements may not be as such it right now, but in future when you get thrown by corner cases that time it will be a big headache.

Comment: @VinnyKaur : and since the onus here too is on operations of `date`, its better to proceed to doing so with the correct `datetime` structure.